# python one-line if statement calling function if true

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm using argparse.

```
def help():
  parser.print_help()
  sys.exit(0)

help() if (args.lock and args.unlock)
```

This gives me a syntax error. What is wrong with my if statement?

Comment: try this: `if (args.lock and args.unlock): help()`

Comment: *"What is wrong w/ my if statement?"* - it's syntactically invalid, hence the error. Why do you want do do it in one line anyway?

Comment: thanks. i ended up using if <statement>: help(). i haven't found a good way to parse all the arguments, esp when i have 3 and only 1 is required, and i wanted it in one line for clarity. i come from perl where it was a similar syntax.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions): `true_result if condition else false_result`. A conditional expression *requires* an `else` part, because it *has* to produce a value; i.e. when the condition is false, there has to be an expression to produce the result in that case.

Don't use a conditional expression when all you want is a proper `if` statement:

```
if args.lock and args.unlock: help()
```